# The art of programming: Python vs C#

Tags: c#, python

Over the last few years I have grown rather fond of python. I enjoy coding in it a lot more than in other languages. Recently, a coworker told me that he preferred C#. I am having a hard time understanding his choice. When ever I code with C# I feel like its Java but for Microsoft products only. He also added that he is very pleased with the work Microsoft has put into C#. This seems to contradict what I have been lead to believe.

Anyways, which language would you say is more expressive? Which would you use to develop an application and why? What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of using one over the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Mike -- this would be better asked on programmers.stackexchange.com (I believe.)

Comment: Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about the kind of questions that should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why is it ok for people to ask these then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447118/programming-in-python-vs-programming-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610199/the-art-of-programming-java-vs-c

Comment: Because , they have high reputation , i think :)