# Package up Python files

Tags: python, packaging

I have a folder:

```
tastyfood
```

I have four classes:

```
chocolate.py
sweets.py
crisps.py
tuna.py
```

Say I wanted to put the four classes in the folder `tastyfood`

So I can make importations like:

```
import tastyfood
```

and all the classes are imported rather than each class being imported.

I understand you can use `__init__.py` and have been reading posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024472/python-define-classes-in-packages) But I am unable to find a way to do what I would like.

Any one have suggestions?

Comment: The answer you link describes exactly what you need to do; what are you stuck on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preamble:** This technique can be useful if you have *big classes* of hundreds lines. If your classes are quite small, you should put them in one single file called `tastyfood.py` and you'll get the same behaviour, without folders.

If you want to use a folder to classify your classes, you need to have this folder structure:

```
tastyfood/
    __init__.py
    chocolate.py
    sweets.py
    crisps.py
    tuna.py

example.py  # example file quoted above
```

and the `__init__.py` can contains import statement to make your life easier:

```
from chocolate import Chocolate
from sweets import Sweet
# ... import everything you want in the tastyfood namespace
```

so these examples, which can be found in `example.py`, can be valid:

```
import tastyfood
choco = tastyfood.Chocolate()

from tastyfood import Chocolate
choco = Chocolate()

from tastyfood.chocolate import Chocolate  # still works too
choco = Chocolate()
```

Answer (score 0):

So all the classes are located in `tastyfood/` , correct? You need to put an empty `__init__.py` file in that folder, along with the other files and you will be able to import them like that.